# Recoger respuesta .bat desde VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Des de VBA ejecuto una bat usando Call Shell(...) y funciona correctamente.

Ahora necesito recoger la respuesta de esta bat, la cual tiene un "Echo respuesta".

¿Alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Gracias,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784508/6241235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me han respondido en SO en Ingles.
Respuesta [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784059/get-an-echo-batch-file-answer-with-vba/51784508#51784508)

Adjunto una traducción.

No puedes devolver una respuesta usando `Call Shell`. Necesitas usar`WScript.Shell`.

```
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim ex As Object
Set ex = sh.Exec("C:\Directorio\A\Archivo.bat")
Dim ans As String
ans = ex.StdOut.ReadAll
```

De forma mas resumida, si quieres ahorrarte líneas:

```
Dim ans As String
ans = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("C:\Directorio\A\Archivo.bat").StdOut.ReadAll
```